# how to expand - collapse in ui grid Grouping on row click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to expand  and collapse the grouping on row click as it should work with + and - icons  in the ui grid.

I am trying to call treeButtonClick(row, $event) from the row template like below. but the function in not triggering.

```
rowTemplate: '<div ng-click="treeButtonClick(row, $event)" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ui-grid-cell></div>',
```

Also this shoud work as equalent to + and - icons, in grouping in ui grid.

Please suggest me how to make it work, Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figured it out? Please, provide a working example if you can.

Comment: NP, I found the solution  :)

Comment: Can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to: 
1. Create custom template for your table:

```
<div ng-mousedown="grid.appScope.onMouseDown(row, $event)"
     ng-click="grid.appScope.onDblClickRow(row.entity)" grid="grid" class="ui-grid-row">
    <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name"
         class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader, custom: true }"
         ui-grid-cell></div>
</div>
```

Specify template to use as rowTemplate and your own app scope provider:

```
vm.gridOptions = {
            appScopeProvider: myAppScopeProvider,
            rowTemplate: 'app/pages/components/building/buildReqViewAll/rowTemplate.html',
            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                vm.gridApi = gridApi;
            }
        };
```

And function that open your row:

```
var myAppScopeProvider = {
            onClickRow: function (row, event) {
                var rowIndex = row.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row);

                if (!angular.isUndefined(row.treeLevel)) {
                    vm.gridApi.treeBase.toggleRowTreeState(vm.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[rowNumber]);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: works like a charm - but small typo ... you set `rowIndex`, then refer to `rowNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to expand all rows, $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows(), same way to collapse you can use collapseAllRows. 
You can add a cellTemplate for that column, where you need '+' and '-' and for that '+' click, you can expand these rows through these functions.